# Make questions listing searchable

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

Sometimes when going through a question listing I want to search for questions with 0 answers; negative votes, etc. I tried with both Firefox and Chrome (latest-ish versions) and I can't find anything if I search for "0 answer" or "0answer." (even when there are questions with no answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To find questions with 0 answers search for `answers:0`, more information on this can be found on the [advanced search options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).
- To find posts with low scores click the votes tab and go to one of the last pages.

If you want a specific search option added I suggest posting a more specific feature request.

Comment: Ah, you mean the `votes` tab

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting [answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0) in your search.  For more options, see the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

Comment: Why isn't there a "hasbounty" search option?

Comment: @Null: I'd ask that as a separate question.